# How to use bsondump in windows

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoid, bson

How to use bsondump and its command in windows.

when i am running bsondump foo.bson > foo.json

error: 'bsondump' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I want to convert a bson file into json file in windows that is generate by mongodb fooRollback() command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your command-line usage is correct. The error message means that you are not at the current directory of MongoDB's bin files, or that you don't have a PATH entry for that directory.

After you have downloaded MongoDB, you will find `bsondump.exe` in the `.\bin\` folder.

Comment: thanks....\bin\ folder is not there so i reinstall my mongodb.....may be it was crashed.

Answer (score 0):

my solution , work for me is:

1. install tools of mongodb of the [link mongo tools](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/shell).
2. click in home in windows, find cmd and run as administrator.
3. find path of mongo server install, in my case is "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin", and copy in terminal, push enter. **Important:" always you should be administrator".**
4. check if you have tool:"bsondump.exe", if you dont have, install tools that before downloaded, if is necesary copy files directly in path:"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin"
5. now you can copy files type bson in this folder bin, in my case:"customer.bson".
6. execute command in terminal before opened, example: "bsondump customer.bson > customer.json"